# What is the best way of filtering by multiple fields in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an entity with 10 fields:

```
Class Details{
  String item; 
  String name; 
  String type;
  String origin; 
  String color; 
  String quality;
  String country;
  String quantity;
  Boolean availability;
  String price;
 }
```

I have a restful endpoint that serves a List. I want the user to be able to provide search filters for each field.
Currently I have QueryParam for each field. Then I filter by using java8 stream:

```
List<Detail> details;
details.stream().filter(detail-> detail.getItem()==item).filter(detail-> detail.getName()==name).....collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If I have 50 other classes with multiple fields that I want to filter, Is there a way of generalizing this?

Comment: This *might* be one of the rare situations where reflection could come in handy: so instead of writing down all attributes "manually" as in your example you could do that "by name" using reflection. But I am wondering how much design went into a model that leads to 50 classes looking like this.

Comment: Don’t compare strings with `==`.  Use the `equals` method or use [Objects.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java .

Answer (score 10):

You can compose such predicates with [`.and()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [`.or()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#or-java.util.function.Predicate-), allowing you to define a single aggregate predicate that applies all the checks you would like, rather than trying to chain *n* `.filter()` calls. This enables arbitrarily complex predicates that can be constructed at runtime.

```
// Note that you shouldn't normally use == on objects
Predicate<Detail> itemPredicate = d-> item.equals(d.getItem());
Predicate<Detail> namePredicate = d-> name.equals(d.getName());

details.stream()
    .filter(itemPredicate.and(namePredicate))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid reflection how about something like this?

```
static enum DetailQueryParams {

    ITEM("item", d -> d.item),
    NAME("name", d -> d.name),
    TYPE("type", d -> d.type),
    ORIGIN("origin", d -> d.origin),
    COLOR("color", d -> d.color),
    QUALITY("quality", d -> d.quality),
    COUNTRY("country", d -> d.country),
    QUANTITY("quantity", d -> d.quantity),
    AVAILABILITY("availability", d -> d.availability),
    PRICE("price", d -> d.price);

    private String name;
    private Function<Detail, Object> valueExtractor;

    private DetailQueryParams(String name, 
            Function<Detail, Object> valueExtractor) {
        this.name = name;
        this.valueExtractor = valueExtractor;
    }

    public static Predicate<Detail> mustMatchDetailValues(
            Function<String, Optional<String>> queryParamGetter) {
        return Arrays.asList(values()).stream()
                .map(p -> queryParamGetter.apply(p.name)
                        .map(q -> (Predicate<Detail>) 
                                d -> String.valueOf(p.valueExtractor.apply(d)).equals(q))
                        .orElse(d -> true))
                .reduce(Predicate::and)
                .orElse(d -> true);
    }

}
```

And then, assuming that you can access query params by e.g. `request.getQueryParam(String name)` which returns a `String` value or `null`, use the code by calling the following:

```
details.stream()
    .filter(DetailQueryParams.mustMatchDetailValues(
            name -> Optional.ofNullable(request.getQueryParam(name))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What the method basically does is:

```
- for each possible query param
    - get its value from the request
    - if value is present build predicate which
        - gets field value from detail object and convert to string
        - check that both strings (queried and extracted) matches
    - if value is not present return predicate that always returns true
- combine resulting predicates using and
- use always true as fallback (which here never actually happens)
```

Of course this could also be extended to generate predicates depending on the actual value type instead of comparing strings so that e.g. ranges could be requested and handled via "priceMin" and/or "priceMax".

Comment: You can also use Arrays.stream(values()) instead of Arrays.asList(values()).stream(). You could also simplify .reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(d -> true) to .reduce(d -> true, Predicate::and).

Answer (score 1):

For Lambda details -> condition. So we can specify how many required.

```
details.stream().filter(detail-> detail.getItem()==item && detail.getName()==name && ...)
```